# KMongo and coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kmongo

I have a question related to coroutines and KMongo. I'm using KMongo CoroutineCollection to find some records in the database. On my local computer it takes <0.5sec but when I do the same thing on development environment it takes 10-25 seconds.

The app runs on Spring Boot Netty server with reactor to support coroutines. I'm using also DGS to set up GraphQL endpoints. The simplified callstack is:

```
DGSQuery suspend fun -> suspend fun |
                                    | -> suspend fun KMongo first CoroutineCollection.find()
                                    | -> suspend fun KMongo second CoroutineCollection.find()
```

It seems the default batchSize is `2`, so I can see multiple queries run under the hood.
My suspicion is that the code operates on 1 thread that is used across the app and that's why it takes much longer on dev vs local (less clients and scheduled operations).
This is how logs look like:

```
[ctor-http-nio-1][][] c.x.d.a.wellreport.***Resolver           : wellReports run
[ctor-http-nio-1][][] c.x.d.d.wellreport.***Service            : all***Provider.invoke() start
[ctor-http-nio-1][][] d.m.w.Mongo***Repository                 : fetchAll started
[tter-2-thread-1][][] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Sending command '{"find": "***", "filter": {}, "batchSize": 100, "$db": "***", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "hdGYjs3YSX6K5y2YJzUJkw==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 56 to database *** on connection [connectionId{localValue:22, serverValue:1902}] to server localhost:27017
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Execution of command with request id 56 completed successfully in 13.32 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:22, serverValue:1902}] to server localhost:27017
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] org.mongodb.driver.operation             : Received batch of 54 documents with cursorId 0 from server localhost:27017
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] d.m.w.Mongo***Repository                 : fetchAll finished
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] c.x.d.d.wellreport.***Service            : all***Provider.invoke() finished
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] c.x.d.d.wellreport.***Service            : positive***Provider.invoke() start
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] w.Mongo***Repository                     : fetchAllPositive start
[tter-2-thread-1][][] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Sending command '{"find": "***", "filter": {"score": {"$gt": 0.0}}, "batchSize": 2, "$db": "***", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "hdGYjs3YSX6K5y2YJzUJkw==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 57 to database *** on connection [connectionId{localValue:22, serverValue:1902}] to server localhost:27017
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Execution of command with request id 57 completed successfully in 5.26 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:22, serverValue:1902}] to server localhost:27017
[ntLoopGroup-3-6][][] org.mongodb.driver.operation             : Received batch of 2 documents with cursorId 6831622277590159417 from server localhost:27017
```

This is how repository class look like:

```kotlin
class MongoXXXScoreRepository(private val collection: CoroutineCollection<MongoXXXScore>) : XXXScoreRepository {
    private val logger by logger()
    override suspend fun fetchAllPositive(): List<XXXScore> {
        logger.info("fetchAllPositive start")
        val result = collection.find(MongoXXXScore::score gt 0.0).toList().map { it.toXXXScore() }
        logger.info("fetchAllPositive start")
        return result
    }
}
```

Interesting part to me is that after calling the first KMongo `.find()` the thread changes to a different one and continues on that thread till the end. This doesn't sound right to me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the default batchSize is 2, so I can see multiple queries run under the hood. My suspicion is that the code operates on 1 thread that is used across the app and that's why it takes much longer on dev vs local

I think multiple round-trip costs is a more likely explanation.
If you have n documents, the time taken is n/2*rtt.

I don't think it's a stretch to imagine your dev environment has a round trip time 20x your local machine.

So an easy fix is to simply increase your `batchSize`.

> the thread changes to a different one and continues on that thread till the end.

This is less surprsing when  you remember coroutines are pretty much callbacks. [`Dispatchers.Default`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html), for example, has a thread pool to schedule multiple coroutines. This is called [M:N threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#M:N_(hybrid_threading)).

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to write, that the latency for dev is high (forgot that DB is on-prem and the rest is in the cloud). Question is why by default bachSize is 2 - that does not make any sense.